# componentDidMount unexpectedly called after move from react-loadable to react.lazy

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-lazy-load

In my project I used to rely on react-loadable to do some code spliting, lazy loading together with react-router. Something like:

```
<Route component={component} />
```

with

```
Component = Loadable({
    loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Analyze" */ "./components/Analyze"),
})
```

The Analyze component implements `componentDidMount` and use router's `history.push` on state change. When a new url is pushed with some parameter changed, but still leading to this same "Analyze" component, only `componentDidUpdate` is called. I updated this code to use React.lazy:

```
<Route component={(_props: any) =>
          <LazyComponentWrapper>
              <Component {..._props} />
          </LazyComponentWrapper>
        } />
```

with

```
Component = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Analyze" */ "./components/Analyze")),
```

and

```
function LazyComponentWrapper({ children }) {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>{LOADING}</div>}>
        {children}
    </Suspense>
  );
```

but now `componentDidMound` is unexpectedly called every time. It's not clear to me wether this have to do with `React.lazy` or with react-router. Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting) maybe its better to move Suspense out of Route component, try this:

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = lazy(() => import('./routes/Home'));
const Component = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Analyze" */ "./components/Analyze"))

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/analyze" component={Component}/>
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: that does the trick. Sorry I missed this piece of doc. Thanks!

Comment: happy to help :)